# Convert rcpp variables into standard C++ variables

Tags: c++, r, type-conversion, rcpp

My input looks like this:

```
Rcpp::NumericMatrix data(dataMatrix);
Rcpp::NumericVector xSize(dataXsize);
Rcpp::NumericVector ySize(dataYsize);
Rcpp::NumericVector tIndexes(testIndexes);
Rcpp::NumericVector cIndexes(controlIndexes);
```

And the external library I'm trying to call has this signature

```
WilcoxonTest(float * _data, int _dataXsize, int _dataYsize, vector<int> * _testIndexes, vector<int> * _controlIndexes);
```

How can I convert the Rcpp data types into C++ standard data types?

Note:

```
 float * _data
```

Is a matrix of floating point values. The library assumes its something like this:

```
 float * _data = new float[dataXsize * dataYsize];
```

Comment: In addition to josilber’s answer: why don’t you just call the R function [`wilcox.test`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html)?

Comment: Because its slow and im implementing it in C++ myself :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a `std::vector<float>` out of your `NumericMatrix`, you can use:

```
std::vector<float> dat = Rcpp::as<std::vector<float> >(data);
```

The numbers in this vector will be stored as they are stored in the matrix in R (e.g. `matrix(1:4, nrow=2)` will result in a vector `1 2 3 4`). If you need the transpose, I would suggest calling `t` from within R.

All that remains for your problem is converting the `vector` into a C-style raw pointer. This can be done with:

```
float* _data = &dat[0];
```

Some words of warning about grabbing raw vectors out of `std::vector` objects: if you later added objects to `dat` or deleted `dat`, the `_data` pointer could become invalid.

You can grab the other parameters through similar use of the `Rcpp::as` function:

```
int _dataXsize = Rcpp::as<int>(xSize);
int _dataYsize = Rcpp::as<int>(ySize);
std::vector<int> _testIndexes = Rcpp::as<std::vector<int> >(tIndexes);
std::vector<int> _controlIndexes = Rcpp::as<std::vector<int> >(cIndexes);
```

Comment: Thanks! Luckily, the data is for read only :) Maybe i can even find a way to make it into vector. Possibly not.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel you don't necessarily get a pointer with `.begin()`. `demangle("std::vector<float>::iterator")`. I get: `"std::__1::__wrap_iter<float*>"`

Comment: @RomainFrancois: is it always needed to make that local copy `std::vector<float>`? Is there no shortcut without involving copies to pass a, let us say, `NumericVector` to a C function expecting a `float *`?