# Passing a vector or matrix from R to a C function using Rcpp without a local copy?

Tags: rcpp

Here's an illustration of what I am currently doing with two functions.

In both cases I am creating a local copies: either an instance of `std::vector<GLfloat>` or of `std::vector<GLdouble>`.

Isn't there a shortcut not involving copies, where I could go from `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` to `GLfloat *`/`GLdouble *` in a more direct way?

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export("glLoadMatrixf")]]
void gl_load_matrixf(Rcpp::NumericMatrix m) {

  std::vector<GLfloat> float_v = Rcpp::as<std::vector<GLfloat> >(m);
  const GLfloat * _float_v = &float_v[0];

  glLoadMatrixf(_float_v);
}

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export("glLoadMatrixd")]]
void gl_load_matrixd(Rcpp::NumericMatrix m) {

  std::vector<GLdouble> double_v = Rcpp::as<std::vector<GLdouble> >(m);
  const GLdouble * _double_v = &double_v[0];

  glLoadMatrixd(_double_v);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system `GLfloat` and `GLdouble` are defined as:

```c
typedef float GLfloat;
typedef double GLdouble;
```

And R's numeric data type is always a `double`. So you can use `&m[0]` or `m.begin()` directly to get something convertible to a `GLdouble *` without the need to copy the data. For `GLfloat` this is not possible, since it requires a (lossy) cast to go from the (64 bit) `double` used by R to a (32 bit) `float`.

Some code as illustration:

```r
Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS="-lGL -lglfw")

Rcpp::sourceCpp(code = '
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export("glLoadMatrixd")]]
void gl_load_matrixd(Rcpp::NumericMatrix m) {

     const GLdouble * _double_v = &m[0];

     glLoadMatrixd(_double_v);
}
')


glLoadMatrixd(matrix(runif(10), 2, 5))
```

BTW, I have no idea what dimensions such a matrix should have. 2x5 is probably incorrect ...

Comment: Ok, that's nice!, so for doubles I don't need to make internal copies. Only the tiny overhead of creating the pointer. Cool! Thanks! I'm thinking that in R-land my matrices will either be integer or numeric (double) so it probably makes sense to use only the GL versions  that have the same word size.

Comment: Is it really always the case that `&m[0]` and `m.begin()` are interchangeable? I'm asking this because Romain François in a comment to Dirk says that he does not necessarily get a pointer with `.begin()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362844/convert-rcpp-variables-into-standard-c-variables/21364534#comment103048435_21364534

Comment: @rmagno Using the same size(s) as R does simplify things. It would make sense to `assert` it, though. In my experience the the iterator returned by `begin()` (or here better `cbegin()`) is convertible to a pointer for simple array types. But I am not sure that this is guaranteed.